# create new dict from old dict values？

Tags: python

## Goal

```
old_dct= {'A':'B','B':'C','C':'D','D':'E','F':'G','G':'K'}


new_dct = {'A':['B','C','D','E']
          ,'B':['C','D','E']
           ,'C':['D','E']
           ,'D':['E']
           ,'F':['G','K']
          ,'G':['K']}
```

The keys of `new_dct` is the same as `old_dct`. The values of new_dct is the value of old_dct based on keys. If the value is still in old_dct keys, then value should be update and the type is list. For example, 'A' is the key of `old_dct` and its value is `B` and B is the key of 'old_dct' and its value is `C` and so on. So the values of `A` in `new_dct` is `['B','C','D','E']`.

Comment: Where is `G` and `K`?

Comment: @U12-Forward. 'G' is the key of in old_dct and 'K' is not.

Answer (score 1):

```
old_dct= {'A':'B','B':'C','C':'D','D':'E','F':'G','G':'K'}

def get_values(letter, old_dict, values):
    if letter in old_dict:
        values.append(letter)
        new_letter = old_dict[letter]
        return get_values(new_letter, old_dict, values)
    values.append(letter)
    return values

new_dict = {}

for key, value in old_dct.items():
    new_dict[key] = get_values(value, old_dct, [])

print(new_dict)
```

output

```
{'A': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'B': ['C', 'D', 'E'], 'C': ['D', 'E'], 'D': ['E'], 'F': ['G', 'K'], 'G': ['K']}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
old_dct= {'A':'B','B':'C','C':'D','D':'E','F':'G','G':'K'}

def itr_dct(key):
    lst = [] 
    g = key
    while old_dct.get(key) and g:
        g = old_dct.get(g)
        lst.append(g)
    return lst[:-1]

{k : itr_dct(k) for k,v in old_dct.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 'B': ['C', 'D', 'E'],
 'C': ['D', 'E'],
 'D': ['E'],
 'F': ['G', 'K'],
 'G': ['K']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a first approach (not too efficient because recalculates a lot of paths) like this:

```py
old_dct= {'A':'B','B':'C','C':'D','D':'E','F':'G','G':'K'}
new_dct = {}
for l in old_dct:
    current_path = []
    k = l
    while k in old_dct and k is not None:
      k = old_dct.get(k,None)
      if k:
        current_path.append(k)
    new_dct [l] = current_path
```

If you don't want to recalculate paths, you could check if the path of the current letter was already calculated:

```py
old_dct= {'A':'B','B':'C','C':'D','D':'E','F':'G','G':'K'}
new_dct  = {}
for l in old_dct:
  if l not in new_dct :
    current_path = []
    k = l
    while k in old_dct and k is not None:
      k = old_dct.get(k,None)
      if k:
        current_path.append(k)
      if k in new_dct :
        current_path.extend([k]+new_dct [k])
        break
    new_dct [l] = current_path
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def staggered_dict(d):
    l = []
    new_d = {}

    for key, value in d.items():
        temp_d = {**d}
        temp_d.pop(key)
        l.append(value)

        while value in temp_d:
            l.append(temp_d[value])
            temp_d = {**temp_d}
            value = temp_d.pop(value)

        new_d[key] = l
        l = []

    return new_d


old_dct = {'A':'B','B':'C','C':'D','D':'E','F':'G','G':'K'}
new_dct = staggered_dict(old_dct)
print(new_dct)
```

Out:

`{'A': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'B': ['C', 'D', 'E'], 'C': ['D', 'E'], 'D': ['E'], 'F': ['G', 'K'], 'G': ['K']}`